# php include isnt working

Tags: php, nginx, include

I have a server, and  I decided to update the OS, php was also updated from php5 to php7.  In the web pages, I have includes to get layout info.
like this:

```
<html><body>
<?php include "scripts/sidebar.php";?>
</body></html>
```

(For example). 
The php files individually work, but the web pages do not INCLUDE the files in the include statements. Formerly, this had been working. I have looked for errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log and /var/log/nginx/access.log, there are none.
There are also no errors in /var/log/php7.0-fpm.log

I tried changing the php.ini file variable "include_path" to point to the location of the scripts, (and reload nginx and php), but this had no effect.

I tried setting "allow_url_include = On" as described in the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php
  After restarting php, and nginx, this seemed to have no effect.

What can I do to make the `<?php include 'scripts/sidebar.php';?>` function work?

Comment: php functions does not work with `.html` extension.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use like this.

```
include_once './test.php';
```

all files in same directory

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned your file name from where you are including the php file, if your file extension is php then it will work.

Try to use

```
<?php include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/scripts/sidebar.php"); ?>
```